# Keeping files on VM in sync with local files with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control

I'm working a lot with Virtual Machines and look for an efficient way to easily manipulate the files on the VM while still having them in sync with my local filesystem from where I commit them to the VCS.

I tried the remote Remote Systems Explorer for Eclipse. This gives me easy access to the files on the remote system, but has no synchronize option. So I can work directly on the remote files, but I need to sync it back to my local directory to commit them.

Basically I need some kind of `rsync` (Windows machine though) so that i only need to manipulate either my local files and sync the VM files or vice versa.

Can anybody help with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your reputation, I guess you can probably create some script to synchronize the local files on the command line outside Eclipse. If so, then you can have this script be invoked automatically from Eclipse as part of your normal (automated) project build. To do so, you only have to add a new builder to the project, which invokes that script.

[image]

[This tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) shows how to invoke an ant script during each build. You can restrict the invoked builder to changes of specific files and working sets, if you don't want to trigger that script on *each* file change.